# How can I calculate percentile for every single data inside an xarray dataset

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, python-xarray, percentile

I have a dataset of one variable with the dimension of time, lat, Lon. The dataset looks like the following and it has several grids where there is NaN values:

```
 <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time = 6300, latitude: 300, longitude: 360)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 49.62 49.88 50.12 50.38 ... 70.88 71.12 71.38
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -9.875 -9.625 -9.375 ... 39.38 39.62 39.88
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-06-01 1950-06-02 ... 2018-08-31
Data variables:
    precip (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(6300, 300, 360)
```

I want to calculate the percentile of each value within the dataset. The desired xarray dataset will be like the following. Please note that I will be calculating percentile along time axis (for each pixels, want to use the timeseries to of the corresponding pixel during calculation of the percentile):

```
 <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time = 6300, latitude: 300, longitude: 360)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 49.62 49.88 50.12 50.38 ... 70.88 71.12 71.38
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -9.875 -9.625 -9.375 ... 39.38 39.62 39.88
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-06-01 1950-06-02 ... 2018-08-31
Data variables:
    precip_percentile (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(6300, 300, 360)
```

I did some exploring and I am using the following code to calculate the percentile using xarray.ufunc:

```
def percentileofscore_weak(x):
    return stats.percentileofscore(x, x, kind='rank')

# Apply percentileofscore_weak along the time axis using apply_ufunc
percentiles = xr.apply_ufunc(
    percentileofscore_weak,
    mean_month,
    input_core_dims=[['time']],
    output_core_dims=[[]],
    dask='parallelized',  # Enable parallelization for large datasets
    dask_gufunc_kwargs={'allow_rechunk': False}
)
```

The above code generates a percentile like following:

xarray.DataArray 'percentile' lat: 300, lon: 360. That means it took the time dimension away.

How can I calculate percentile for individual values using each grid's corresponding timeseries and generate an xarray dataset like following:

```
 <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time = 6300, latitude: 300, longitude: 360)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 49.62 49.88 50.12 50.38 ... 70.88 71.12 71.38
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -9.875 -9.625 -9.375 ... 39.38 39.62 39.88
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-06-01 1950-06-02 ... 2018-08-31
Data variables:
    precip_percentile (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(6300, 300, 360)
```

Comment: Why is this a hard problem to solve? You know how to sort the values. What novel aspect of this problem prevents sorting from immediately providing a solution? Is it maybe the absence of a unique ID on each row, some detail like that?

Comment: @J_H, I am not sure about your question, and I am sure you did not understand the problem. It is indeed very simple if the dataset is at a single location with one single timeseries or a few rows and columns. But my dataset is pretty big (consisting of 150 years of daily data with 3600 rows and 1500 columns). So, I needed something like xarray.ufunc that can handle the big size of data by iterating every single grid and replacing every single value with its corresponding percentile. But I was not able to use xarray.ufunc here, which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: It sounds like viewing the problem through the lens of the ufunc API may be constraining the current problem solving approach. Let's take a step back. Suppose we had only two weeks of data, covering just a few square kilometers. Surely it would be an easy problem then, yes? Can we apply that to the bigger problem? // We can exploit monotonicity of the underlying measures. Suppose we sampled just 10% of the dataset, at regular intervals. Or an even smaller sample, maybe 1%, so the data fits in RAM and can be sorted. Could we interpolate results, when reading _all_ the original data?

Comment: I have 240GB of RAM in a high-end computing and still I was not able to run the code successfully.